# Capacidade armazenamento MySql

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela em MySql que faço backup diariamente, tenho hoje nela 552 registros, mas das duas ultimas vezes que fiz o backup percebi que só estavam salvando 487 registros.
Como faço pra aumentar a capacidade de armazenamento de uma tabela do MySql?
Para realizar o backup eu clico com o botão direito no banco e seleciono a opção "Exportar banco de dados como SQL" na nova janela que se abre eu seleciono os dois itens de "Criar" seleciono o caminho a qual desejo salvar e pronto.

Comment: Não parece ser problema com a capacidade de armazenamento, visto que 487 é um número relativamente baixo. Cada registro ocupa muita memória?

Comment: Não, é somente texto, tenho neste momento 543 registros  com 240,0KiB de armazenamento.

Comment: Então realmente o problema não é a capacidade do banco. Possivelmente seja falha na importação ou algo do gênero. Veja se consegue [edit] a pergunta e dar mais detalhes de como está fazendo a exportação e importação dos dados.

Comment: OK, vou detalhar, me informe se estou realizando da maneia correta.

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a [documentação do MySQL 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-size-limit.html) sobre o limite no tamanho das tabelas, diz:

**C.10.3 Limites no tamanho da tabela**

> O tamanho máximo efetivo da tabela para bancos de dados MySQL
>   geralmente é determinado pelas restrições do sistema operacional em
>   tamanhos de arquivos, e não pelos limites internos do MySQL. Para
>   obter informações atualizadas sobre os limites do tamanho do arquivo
>   do sistema operacional, consulte a documentação específica do seu
>   sistema operacional.
>
> Usuários do Windows, note que FAT e VFAT (FAT32) não são considerados
>   adequados para uso de produção com o MySQL. Use o NTFS em vez disso.
>
> Se você encontrar um erro de tabela completa, há várias razões pelas
>   quais ele pode ter ocorrido:
>
> O disco pode estar cheio.
>
> - Você está usando *InnoDB* nas tabelas e ficou sem espaço em um InnoDB arquivo de espaço de tabela. O tamanho máximo do *tablespace*
>     também é o tamanho máximo para uma tabela.
> - Geralmente, o compartilhamento de tabelas em vários arquivos de    *tablespace* é recomendado para tabelas com tamanho maior que 1 TB.
> - Você atingiu um limite de tamanho de arquivo do sistema operacional.    Por exemplo, você está usando MyISAM nas tabelas em um
>     sistema operacional que suporta arquivos de até 2GB de tamanho e você
>     atingiu esse limite para o arquivo de dados ou arquivo de índice.
> - Você está usando uma MyISAM nas tabela e o espaço necessário para a    tabela excede o permitido pelo tamanho do ponteiro interno.    MyISAM
>     permite que dados e arquivos de índice cresçam até 256 TB por
>     padrão, mas esse limite pode ser alterado para o tamanho máximo
>     permitido de 65,536 TB (256 7 - 1 bytes).

Ou seja, o problema não está no MySQL. Talvez se postar alguns trechos de código podemos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Como devo proceder entao para fazer o backup? pois quando eu dou o comando :select MAX(id) from minhaTabela ele mostra o total de registros

Comment: A estrutura que está tentando importar não contém nenhum erro de formação? Por exemplo quando tenta informar sempre para no mesmo dígito 487 registros? O registro 488 segue a mesma formatação que os anteriores no arquivo?

Comment: Então os dados estão corretos, uma coisa que percebi que nao estou entendendo é o seguinte: o backup que fiz mês passado quando eu dou o comando para saber a quantidade de registros que tenho ele informa a quantidade atual,acho que estou fazendo o backup dos dados de maneira errada, poderia me auxiliar de como fazer o backup? estou usando o HEIDISQL

Comment: veja se esse links [como fazer backup](https://portal.universonet.com.br/kb/a197/como-fazer-backup-do-banco-mysql-com-o-heidisql.aspx) e [como importar e exportar](https://support.appliedi.net/kb/a1034/how-to-import-and-export-a-mysql-database-using-heidisql.aspx) te ajuda. Assim iremos partir deste post para verificar os erros que acontece.